# Unit Testing, Current Directory and Application Path

Tags: c#, unit-testing

When coding parts of an application that require access to a directory, I often write the code so that if the Directory is specified using a relative path, the system assumes that the intent is to use a directory subordinate to the directory/folder that the Application (Executable) is running in (or was loaded from).

But when I run Unit Tests which exercise this code, it turns out that the Application path is a completely different directory, because the "Application " is the Test runner Harness, and it is running in a separate directory.

For writes this is no problem, but if the code is attempting to read a file configured in the solution as [Content] from a directory that the compiler copied as part of the build process, this file is of course not in the Test Runner version of the folder at all.

This can be resolved for files that are physically in the test project solution space, (by adding additional instructions on TestRunner configuration), but as far as I know, if the file is specified in the Solution as a link to a physical file located outside the project space, then I have yet to be able to find a simple solution to the problem.

What solutions to this issue exist? and what are the pros/cons of each one?

Comment: Decouple tight coupling by abstracting access to file system. That way you can inject your own implementation for testing that provide the desired results.

Comment: But in this case that would not solve the problem as the injected implementation would still need to read the same file and would need to somehow construct the correct file spec from the available data in the unit test. (these files are large xml files that represent data package for complex process. And there are 100+ different files to represent various test cases.